# tocloft does not add all \cftaddnumtitle entries to ToC

Tags: pdfpages, tocloft

I am including PDF documents and using `tocloft \cftaddnumtitleline` to recreate Table of Content elements in the included documents. I expect the ToC to look like this:

[image]

The ToC actually looks like this:
[image]

I am able to create the expected ToC with the addition of the line labeled `%% <--- HERE`, which suggests `cftaddnumtitleline` additions to the ToC aren't being added unless followed by an ordinary ToC entry.

Why is this, and is there a better way to get the ToC entries to appear without using the workaround I found (which has the side effect of adding a blank page)?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\addsection}[3]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\protect\numberline{#1}#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\addsubsection}[3]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{\protect\numberline{#1}#2}{#3}}}

%% Headings for chapter
\fancypagestyle{chapter}
{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries{\MakeUppercase{Chapter title}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries{Chapter Number}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

%% Insert a blank page for oddside start
\newcommand*\cleartorightpage{%
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \clearpage
  \hbox{}\newpage
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\cleartorightpage 
\pagestyle{chapter}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\includepdf[pages={2-4}, pagecommand={}]{Include}
\cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{1}{Example Section 1}{4}
\cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{2}{Example Section 2}{5}
\cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{3}{Example Section 3}{6}

\pagestyle{chapter}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\includepdf[pages={2-4}, pagecommand={}]{Include}
\cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{1}{Example Section 1}{8}
\cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{2}{Example Section 2}{9}
\cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{3}{Example Section 3}{10}

\chapter*{} %% <--- HERE: Why is this needed?

\end{document}
```

(This generates the file Include.pdf, which is used in the minimal example):

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,openany]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\cleartoleftpage{%
  \clearpage
  \ifodd\value{page}\hbox{}\newpage\fi
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\cleartoleftpage  % Start evenside.
\doublespacing
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably used the build in interface for this in pdfpages. Your commands are executed after the pages are included, but without anything else on that page it is never shipped out, and thus your three lines are never executed

Comment: Do you mean using `\addtotoc` and similar commands from `pdfpages` instead of `tocloft`? These are marked as experimental, which is why I did not want to use them. But I can confirm that adding literally anything instead of `\chapter` does lead to the page being shipped.

The actual situation is a little more complicated, in that the included PDFs are in the middle of the document, but somehow the ToC commands still aren't being added, although the content after it is.

Comment: So far `addtoc` has worked fine for us (the authors marks is as experiment in that the syntax many change). Note that it is limited in that it cannot directly do unnumbered entries (like a link to a bibliography in the included PDF), but there are certain ways to cheat.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I normally do (I reoved a lot of code that seems irrelevant for this question).

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\includepdf[pages={2-4},
addtotoc={% first number is the page number in the included PDF 
  2,section,1,Example Section 1,sec11,%
  3,section,1,Example Section 2,sec12,%
  4,section,1,Example Section 3,sec13%
},
]{Include}

A reference: \ref{sec12} on page~\pageref{sec12}


\chapter{Chapter Two}
\includepdf[pages={2-4},%pagecommand={}
addtotoc={% first number is the page number in the included PDF 
  2,section,1,Example Section 1,sec21,%
  3,section,1,Example Section 2,sec22,%
  4,section,1,Example Section 3,sec23%
},
]{Include}
\end{document}
```

This also has the benefit that it works independently of the page numbers in your document (you seemed to be hard coding page numbers in your original code).

Comment: I'll give this a try next time for sure (for this time around, I'm not really keen to renumber 300+ pages with relative page locations instead of absolute ones, so I will use a `\phantom` workaround).

Comment: @Ann may I ask why you opt to collect 300+ pages this way?

Comment: The chapters were written independently, and make use of incompatible libraries.

Comment: @Ann I hope they at least look similar, which incompatible libs? Most things can be merged, if you know how and is prepared to take the time